# C# - Make form semi-transparent while moving

Tags: c#, events, forms, move, transparent

Is there any way to make the form semi-transparent while it is being moved and then become opaque when it's not being moved anymore?  I have tried the `Form_Move` event with no luck.
 I'm stuck, any help?

Comment: You changed the Form.Opacity Property in the Form_Move event?

Comment: Yes but when the program is first ran, it's semi-transparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the form loads as semi-transparent is because the form has to be moved into the starting position, which triggers the Move event. You can overcome that by basing whether the opacity is set, on whether the form has fully loaded.

The ResizeEnd event fires after a form has finished moving, so something like this should work:

```
bool canMove = false;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    canMove = true;
}

private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (canMove)
    {
        this.Opacity = 0.5;
    }
}

private void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Opacity = 1;
}
```

Comment: Nice one!  I didn't know that ResizeEnd fired when the user finished moving a form.  I notice that ResizeBegin fires when the user starts moving a form, so maybe he could use this rather than the Form_Load / canMove / Form_Move trick?

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is perfect!  I'll experiment with it even more.  By the way, love your avatar Bauer ;).

Comment: Anyone having problems when using the Windows keys to move the window to a certain Tile position on-screen?
For instance, when I use Windows+LeftKey, the form stays Opaque and it won't reset back to normal until I resize it manually again.
So what I did to fix that problem is to take @itowlson 's advice and use Form1_ResizeBegin instead of Form1_Move. That seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

To do it *properly* I expect you'd need to override the message processing to respond to the title bar being held, etc. But you could cheat, and just use a timer so that you make it opaque for a little while when moved, so continuous movement works:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    using (Form form = new Form())
    using (Timer tmr = new Timer())
    {
        tmr.Interval = 500;
        bool first = true;
        tmr.Tick += delegate
        {
            tmr.Stop();
            form.Opacity = 1;
        };
        form.Move += delegate
        {
            if (first) { first = false; return; }
            tmr.Stop();
            tmr.Start();
            form.Opacity = 0.3;
        };
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Obviously you could tweak this to fade in/out, etc - this is just to show the overall concept.

Comment: I get an error saying "SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application."

Comment: So do that... I don't get that error, presumably culture related.

Comment: Ok, I put Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); before everything else and it runs.  But no transparency when the form is moved.