# How to make a form show up like on Paint.NET

Tags: c#, forms

I am trying to figure out how to make a form show up like is on the Paint.NET Program, like the History, Colors, Etc

[image]

Like where they fade out over where the painting is.
Is there any way that this can be done?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to know how to create a semi transparent form?

Comment: Yes, That is exactly what i want to do.

Comment: This looks relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584239/c-sharp-make-form-semi-transparent-while-moving

Comment: This could also help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368783/transparent-form-background

Comment: I tried doing the Opacity, but it makes the whole thing 50% Opacity and i only want that is in the inside to be at 50% Opacity and not the whole thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

both Winforms `Form` and WPF / Silverlight `Window` have an `Opacity` property. Set that to something below 1.